# Linux utility to add a command line history buffer to any executable that gets input from STDIN?

Tags: linux, command-line, command-history

A long time I was working on a Linux setup that had a great utility to add a command line history buffer to any executable that read from stdin.

So if you have a Linux executable, for example a command line oriented C++ program, every time that executable read from stdin, you could use the up and down arrows to scroll aback and forth through your previous inputs just like you can do in a plain terminal window.  In other words, the executable "inherited" a command line history buffer when it didn't have one before.

Does anyone know what utility I am talking about?  You launched it at the command line and had it load the Linux executable you wanted "wrapped" as one of the command line arguments to the utility.  I simply can't remember the name of that tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several, for example [rlwrap](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap) and `cle`. Most are based on the [readline library](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html)